# Creating a function $f(x)$ such that $f(0) = 10$ and the instantaneous percentage growth rate of $f(x)$ is a steady $25\%$?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

The function I came up with is $10e^{0.25x}$. I took the initial condition of $f(0) = 10$ and placed it into an exponential function:

> $$ae^{0.25x} = 10$$

When $x = 0$, $a = 10$ as well.

However, since the rate is a steady $25\%$, shouldn't $f(1) = 12.5$? When I calculate, I am getting $12.84$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct function and the correct result for $f(1)$.  This is the effect of [compound interest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest).  If you start thinking about paying $25\%$ at the end of the year the final balance would be $12.5$  If you pay $12.5\%$ twice, you get $1.125^2=1.265625$ because the interest paid at the first period draws interest at the end.  As the intervals get shorter and the number of payments gets greater you approach a multiplier of $\exp(i)$ and $\exp(0.25)\approx 1.284$ as you found.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about the compounding example.